# Website down after installing an extension for magento

Tags: php, magento, merge

I installed the Inchoo Social Connect extension for Magento.

I enabled compiler and merged all the files from zip with my current files in httpdocs. The website gives this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFwL3.png).

Comment: Please do not refer to images for error messages. Add them in plain text to your SO question. In this case most of the text would have been fine to add with shortened paths. Also provide a short summary for the replication of the problem. Also known as a [mcve].

Comment: hope the extension came with an Un-install

Comment: Error is very clear.  Look at filename string passed to [`is_readable`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) in that code. Not just a `basedir` issue?

Comment: @rtfm nice snag on the username :) They not allow 4 letters ones till more recently or something?